# Scanner double value - InputMismatchException

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I tried use scanner at easiest way:

**Code:**

```
double gas, efficiency, distance, cost;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the number of gallons of gas in the tank: ");
gas = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the fuel efficiency: ");
efficiency = scanner.nextDouble();
```

But after first input `5.1` it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    at udacity.MileagePrinter.main(MileagePrinter.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) state:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the
>       pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

But to my mind all look correctly, and should work OK.

**Questions:**

- Why this happen at this situation?
- How to circumvent this trouble?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the snippet of code you've provided, the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Without specifying the Locale, your `.` should probably be a `,` in your Locale

Comment: @Tdorno depends on what locale you are using, maybe you are using US-locale

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should precise a Locale for your Scanner.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers) :

> An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the
> standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A
> scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the
> Locale.getDefault() method; it may be changed via the
> useLocale(java.util.Locale) method
> The localized formats are defined in terms of the following
> parameters, which for a particular locale are taken from that locale's
> DecimalFormat object, df, and its and DecimalFormatSymbols object,
> dfs.

So your default locale use certainly a DecimalFormat that expect a comma as a decimal delimiter instead of a dot.

Comment: `.useLocale()` returns `this`, you can shorten that to `new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US)`

Comment: I tried running this program but couldn't face any problem. May I know why is that?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar probably because in your JVM's default locale, the decimal number separator is the dot

Comment: @nazar_art import the correct package; `Locale` is in `java.util.Locale`

Comment: @nazar_art you are using Intellij IDEA? Imports should be automatic... At worst it asks you what to import.

Comment: @ZouZou Yes Intellij IDEA. And it gives import only after `Alt` + `Enter`

Comment: And after that import Locale `import java.util.Locale;` (I'm beginner so it took few seconds to understand whats wrong in my code :P )

Comment: Instead of Locale.US, use Locale.ROOT. This is documented as "the language/country neutral locale for the locale sensitive operations". A user in Europe or Asia shouldn't have to use the locale of some random foreign country like the US.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are using the correct locale

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Maybe you are using a locale where "," is the decimal delimiter

Comment: Yes you are right, when I tryed `5,1` all was OK. I can change this as any defalt value?

Comment: I believe if you go to "region and language" if you have windows, you can change the locale to whatever locale you need.

Comment: I newly user Of Ubunta 12.04 (since 2 weeks)

Comment: try this then: http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/01/how-to-change-your-default-locale-on.html

Comment: Locale was the issue when I faced the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551133/nextdouble-method-throwing-an-exception-on-passing-values-with-decimals