# Confusion regarding a double entry in Java

Tags: java

I have written the following code:

```
package buck;

import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = bucky.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = bucky.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

When I mention a double number when entering the first number, it doesn't go to the second instruction and I get what is follow:

```
Enter first number: 
12.2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at buck.apples.main(apples.java:10)
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Give us an example of input.

Comment: Runs fine here. Show us what you entered.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please check again the question , I have just edited its content.

Comment: Do the following `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`. It might be your Locale is off.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150627/scanner-double-value-inputmismatchexception. Possible duplicate.

Comment: I imputed 12.2 two times and 24.4 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You must be entering not a double.
E.g. 2.15 is a double number
but 2,15 is not.

Comment: I just did 12.2 please check the edit that I have made.

Comment: If you're in a French locale (like me), you need to enter 2,15 and not 2.15