# This was written in java 12 but if I run it on java 15, it throws an exception error

Tags: java

I used **scanner.NextFloat()** but if I try to input float number it throws an error, however if I type int numbers it successfully converts into a double or float, what's the problem?
Written in java 12, I'm trying to run it on java 15.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Principal: ");
        float principal = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate: ");
        float annualInterestRate = scanner.nextFloat();
}
}
```

```
Principal: 88888
Annual Interest Rate: 9.8
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Could be the problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244290/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexception-using-nextfloat

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997094/scanner-next-throws-java-util-inputmismatchexception-for-float-but-not-for-in) a similar question, but I'm not sure why it works in Java 12.

Comment: Most likely, it's a Locale related issue.  Did you try to specify locale for Scanner: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);` ?

Comment: @MDK thank you man, this really helped, though I still don't understand why is it like that.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I did, I used Locale.US

Comment: @Alex please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Bill what is your normal locale? I suspect it has to do with the decimal separator. As in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a `Locale` related issue.

Specifying locale for `Scanner`:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

should help resolve scanning float/double numbers using `.` as a decimal separator.